# How to select all children which are in the top of specific element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing

I have a dynamic HTML structure. So, I want to select all content which are behind of `div.test`:

```
<div>
    /* I want to select everythis is here */
    <span class = "test">
</div>
```

---

**Example1:**

```
<div>
    hello
    <span class = "test">
</div>
```

I want this output: `hello`

---

**Example2:**

```
<div>
    this is a <a href="www.example.com">test</a>
    <span class = "test">
</div>
```

I want this output: `this is a <a href="www.example.com">test</a>`

Also here is a image of my real structure:

[image]

Comment: `jQuery( "span.test" ).remove()` ?

Comment: Is the `span` with the `test` class always there? That would make it much simpler.

Comment: Where is this "`div.test`"?

Comment: No, there is not **only** that `span` in the `div`. there is some more elements which I didn't mention to them. `span` is just a clue (boundary).

Comment: So you can not rely on `<span class="test">` being there, right?

Comment: @squint wrong, there is always `<span class="test">` there. And I always want all elements before (behind) it.

Comment: That's easier then. Are there more than one of these on a page, or just the one?

Comment: @squint good question...! yes there is, but don't worry about it. you just give me a solution to select all previous-`span.test`-elements, and then I will use `$(this).closest(".classname")` to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your #2 Example:

```
<div>
    this is a <a href="www.example.com">test</a>
    <span class = "test">
</div>
```

Using this jquery:

```
var content = $('div').html().split($('span.test')[0].outerHTML)[0].trim();

console.log(content);
```

It will output:

```
this is a <a href="www.example.com">test</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/swdn2ews/1/

---

**EDIT:**

This is the jsfiddle with as close to the real structure the OP had: http://jsfiddle.net/bbvyps2p/1/

Comment: This solution works in here... But I don't know why doesn't work for me in reality. I think I asked my question badly. anyway thanks, +1

Comment: Your solution is interesting, it is just one line of code and there is not even one if-statement ...! So can you please take a look at my real structure (I add a photo to my question) and set your answer with that? tnx

Comment: @stack sure, lemme set it up in a jsfiddle